# How to strip out 0x0a special char from utf8 file using c# and keep file as utf8?

Tags: c#, utf-8, character-encoding, replace

The following is a line from a UTF-8 file from which I am trying to remove the special char (0X0A), which shows up as a black diamond with a question mark below:

> 2464577 外國法譯評 True    s6620178    Unspecified <1>�1009-672

This is generated when SSIS reads a SQL table then writes out, using a flat file mgr set to code page 65001.

When I open the file up in Notepad++, displays as 0X0A.

I'm looking for some C# code to definitely strip that char out and replace it with either nothing or a blank space.

Here's what I have tried:

```
        string fileLocation = "c:\\MyFile.txt";
        var content = string.Empty;
        using (StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(fileLocation))
        {
            content = reader.ReadToEnd();
            reader.Close();
        }



        content = content.Replace('\u00A0', ' ');
        //also tried: content.Replace((char)0X0A, ' '); 
        //also tried: content.Replace((char)0X0A, ''); 
        //also tried: content.Replace((char)0X0A, (char)'\0'); 
        Encoding encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(fileLocation, FileMode.Create))
        {
          using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(stream, encoding))
          {
            writer.Write(encoding.GetPreamble()); //This is for writing the BOM
            writer.Write(content);
          }
        }
```

I also tried this code to get the actual string value:

```
byte[] bytes = { 0x0A };
string text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

And it comes back as "\n". So in the code above I also tried replacing "\n" with " ", both in double quotes and single quotes, but still no change.

At this point I'm out of ideas. Anyone got any advice?

Thanks.

Comment: what are you using to view the contents of your file?

Comment: @user1013388: Have you tried running it through a [Unicode character search](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm)? It looks like it's U+FFFC or U+FFFD.

Comment: 0x0A is just a line feed. I'm not sure why it wouldn't form part of a well-formed UTF-8 document, and I don't think you should need to remove it.

Comment: Using Notepad++ to look at the file but also looking at contents in VS after replacement. Haven't tried Unicode search. If it's just a linefeed which the translation shows it is, then why wouldn't the linefeed be manifest int he viewing of the file, ie, why is't the text after that char showing on the next line?

Answer (score 0):

may wanna have a look at regex replacement, for a good example of this, take a look at the post towards the bottom of this page... 
    http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1b523d24-dab6-4870-a9ca-5d313d1ee602/invalid-character-returned-from-webservice

Comment: I think this may be working for me. Have run a few more tests. If it does I'll come back and mark it up+. Thanks!!

Comment: No problem, I had a somewhat similar situation myself a while ago, in this case, it was stripping those sorts of characters out of an XML document before pushing it off elsewhere (they aren't valid in a standard XML document and make some things go haywire when reading them in)

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the string to a char array and loop through the array.
Then check what char the black diamond is and just remove it.

Comment: The files can be pretty large and looping char by char wouldn't be a good solution here. But thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
string content = "blahblah" + (char)10 + "blahblah"; 

char find = (char)10;

content = content.Replace(find.ToString(), "");
```